# Unable to draw a bitmap as it is downloaded on a canvas

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, android-imageview

I'm downloading an image from a website which will be shown on an imageview.

i want the image to appear on the imageview **as it is downloaded** and **not to wait for the entire image be downloaded**. what i mean is if the image is 10000 bytes and the first bytes to be downloaded are 1024, then an image should be constructed from the 1024 bytes **and form the part of image downloaded and draw it on a canvas**

```
byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] writtenOnes;



                while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    filebytes = Files.toByteArray(media);
                    status = (100 * filebytes.length) / contentLength;
                    publishProgress(status);

                }
                fileOutputStream.flush();

                fileOutputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                if( media.length() == contentLength){
                    d(" WELL DONE, FILECOMPLETLY DOWNLOADED. SIZE IS "+ contentLength);
                }else{
                    d(" file not completely downloaded. bytes remaining "+(contentLength -media.length()));
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            return  mediaFile;
        }catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... status) {
        int state = status[0];
        incompleteBitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(filebytes, 0, filebytes.length);

        d(" status is "+ state);
        canvas.drawBitmap(incompleteBitmap,0,0,new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
        progressBar.setProgress(state);
    }
```

I'm unable to create a bitmap from the downloaded bytes. i get a **NullpointerException when i try to get the formed bitmap** on `onProgressUpdate()` method

Q: is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the images are within your domain I have had great results achieving this effect using the Fresco image library which supports the progressive JPEG format. However this may not be desirable if you're looking for a full vanilla solution or are already using another image view library or if the images and format are outwith your control:

[Fresco progressive JPEG documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html)

Comment: everything is under my control including image format and the server that am getting the image. let me try your solution and i will tell you the results

Comment: i have an issue programmatically setting width and height of my simpledraweeview. and i don't see any method in `GenericDraweeHierachy` class and when i use android methods, it's like they aren't been implemented. `simpledrawee.getLayoutParams().width=350`. have you encountered a problem like this?